# Sort a QAbstractListModel with backend list

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qsortfilterproxymodel, qabstractlistmodel

I have a QAbstractListModel-derived C++ class.

```
class MyList : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyList();
 enum {
        SelectedRole,
        DisplayNameRole,
        AddressRole
};

     QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;

    bool setData(const QModelIndex& index, const QVariant& value,
        int role = Qt::EditRole) override;

    private:
    BackEnd backend;
};
```

Then I  have a BackEnd.cpp which adds and removes items to the MyList class object

```
class BackEnd : public QObject {
        // adds item of type MyList to mItems
       bool setItemAt(int index, const Item& item);
    
    private:
    // this has items of type MyList. (i.e QAbstractListModel)
        QVector<Item> mItems;
    }
```

In the Main.cpp I register the MyList type and set the backend to qml root context

```
 qmlRegisterType<MyList >("MyList", 1, 0, "MyListModel");
 engine->rootContext()->setContextProperty("backend", backend);
```

and in QML I  have used

```
ListView {
   model: MyListModel {
        backend: backend
    }
}
```

Now I want to sort my list my list and and have gone through QSortFilterProxyModel but not able to figure out how to fit QSortFilterProxyModel  with my current architecture as my model I have registered as qml type.

Comment: If you need to be able to sort from QML, I recommend [SortFilterProxyModel](https://github.com/oKcerG/SortFilterProxyModel).

Comment: Yes, we need to just add it to Qt already: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-71348